# for in javascript is not working right

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

do not know what it's going
this function
should put
a new player
for each name in the array

```
function newplayer() {
var y = data.playerY;   
var x = data.playerX;

var player ="";
var players={name1:"Jao",name2:"lucas",name3:"pedro",name4:"jorge"}; 

for(var p in players)
{
    player = players[p];
    var xpos = (x-y)*tileH + mapX;
    var ypos = (x+y)*tileH/2+ mapY;

    ctx.drawImage(charImg[0],xpos,ypos-(charImg[0].height/2));  
    //ctx.fillText(player.name, xpos + 10, ypos - (charImg[0].height/2) - 5);
}

}
```

EDIT: managed to get
changing the code
    var player = players [p], for player = players [p];

obrigado vocês que me ajudarão
inclusive Igor

sorry my english I'm from Brazil

Comment: Your foreach code is correct, your problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: remove `var` in `var player = players[p];`

Comment: @Igor that `var` keyword is superfluous, but it's not a bug

Comment: How about a demo fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is with the line you commented out? This one:

```
//ctx.fillText(player.name, xpos + 10, ypos - (charImg[0].height/2) - 5);
```

Because otherwise you don't even need the loop, since you're not using `player` or `p`. If that's true, the problem is `player.name` will be undefined. Considering your object and the way you're looping, `player` will hold the player name. So:

```
ctx.fillText(player, xpos + 10, ypos - (charImg[0].height/2) - 5);
```

Comment: I can put
one
player
I wanted to put more

for each player in the variable players  one player  example:joão one player , lucas player two , pedro tree player                                                      ,disregard this line:    ctx.fillText(player, xpos + 10, ypos - (charImg[0].height/2) - 5);

Comment: We need more details then. Your current loop does nothing with the players, you define `player` but never use it.

Comment: if I put my whole code here you will not be able to understand alias has a client and a server:the User "Igor" helped me.  all my code has more than 120 lines

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are wanting to access the players as an array of players. But the object you are using ins't a collection.

```
function newplayer() {
     var y = data.playerY;   
     var x = data.playerX;

     var players=[
            { name: "Jao" },
            { name: "lucas"},
            { name: "pedro"},
            { name:"jorge" }]; 

     for(var player in players)
     {
         var xpos = (x-y)*tileH + mapX;
         var ypos = (x+y)*tileH/2+ mapY;

         ctx.drawImage(charImg[0],xpos,ypos-(charImg[0].height/2));  
         ctx.fillText(player.name, xpos + 10, ypos - (charImg[0].height/2) - 5);
     }

}
```

If you won't be adding additional information on the player, then you could simply make it an array of strings.